# JS. Ожидание выполнения функции

Tags: javascript, функции, асинхронность, mocha

Только начал изучать JavaScript, требуется Ваша помощь:

```
describe('Test Suite #1', function(){

    it('Check URL Errors', function()
    {   
        assert.equal(checkStatusCode(URL), true);
    });
});
```

Проблема с `assert.equal(...)`, суть в том, что сравнение выполняется до того как закончит выполняться функция. Вопрос как обойти этом момент? Как вообще решаются подобные моменты, когда мне нужно получить результат функции, а потом уже с ним совершать какие-либо действия? Нужны ли для этого `promise`или есть другие варианты?

Спасибо!

@vp_arth, а не подскажете на примере, как из этого сделать nodejs-style функцию с callback ?

```
function checkStatusCode(url, cb){
  if (url == 'right url'){
      cb(null, true);
  }
  else{cb(null, false);}
}
```

Comment: Это решается либо синхронными моками асинхронных функций (ajax, timeout), либо асинхронными тестами.

Comment: Почему вообще Вы пытаетесь проверять, что возвращает функция? Как бы вы получали результат этой функции без тестов?

Comment: Никак, эта функция написана специально для теста. На самом деле этот тест изначально идеологически составлен неверно. Мой вопрос относится скорее не к конкретной реализации именно тут, а в принципе, о том как получать результат одной функции и использовать в другой, не вкладывая их друг в друга.

Comment: Что значит никак? Мы же не знаем, что у Вас там написано. Если `return new Promise(...)` - это одно, если `function(url, next)` - другое.  Мой вопрос в том, **что Вы называете результатом функции**?

Comment: В таких случаях нужно использовать промисы

Comment: "что Вы называете результатом функции?" - согласен, так себе формулировка. Я имею ввиду то, что функция возвращает в конце своей работы. В данном случае это 'return true' или 'false' .

Comment: `return true` - синхронная конструкция, ассинхронные функции возвращают результат иначе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Асинхронные тесты в mocha пишутся довольно просто:

```
describe('Test Suite #1', function(){
  it('Check URL Errors (promise-style function)', function(done) {   
     checkStatusCode(URL)
       .then(function(res) {
         assert.equal(res, true);
         done();  
       });
  });
  it('Check URL Errors (nodejs-callback style function)', function(done) {   
     checkStatusCode(URL, function(err, res) {
       if (err) done(err);
       assert.true(res);
       done();  
     });
  });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! Скажите, пожалуйста, а с чем связано, то что при использовании второго варианта вываливается:     'Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves'

Comment: Ошибка с таймаутом вызывается в случае, если done не был вызван. Просто Ваша функция не является nodejs-style функцией с callback: `function(url, cb) { ... cb(null, true); ... }`